# Class Seating Arrangement

Tags: logical-deduction, combinatorics

There are $25$ students with distinct heights in a class. The seats are arranged in the class like a square array ($5$x$5$) and students are seated such a way that each person will be taller than both the student in front of and left to her/him.

> In **how many different ways** can this operation be done?

**Hint:** If this question was asked for $9$ students with $3$x$3$ square array matrix, then the answer would be $42$.

Comment: The answer is [always 42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42))

Comment: I don't think so. Do that in a 2x2 matrix. Then there are only 24 ways to seat the students and these still include combinations that conflict the given requirement. (Edit: oh i saw the link only now... sorry :-)

Comment: @puck he is making a joke :)

Comment: Hey, you seem to love these kinds of math puzzles. I think you might like [this site proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/119894/math-challenges) (not accessible via Google Chrome, but Safari works). And if you want, you can [join the related chatroom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43767/thesimplifire).

Comment: @user477343 actually i like logic deduction puzzles more than combinatorics and math puzzles. this is an old one so i wanted to share with others

Comment: Ah, well. It's definitely a fun puzzle. I don't have the skills to crack it but I sure enjoy it :D

Comment: @user477343 this kind of puzzle is like finding the way how to do it, not actually solve it manually in my opinion, and learn as well while searching ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> $701149020$

Because

> We may rank the students by height $\{1,2,3,\cdots,25\}$.
>  Since each student must be taller than *any* to their left (in their row) and *any* in front of ("above") them (in their column) then any such square is a [standard Young tableau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau) of shape $(5,5,5,5,5)$ (by definition).
>  The number of standard Young tableau of shape $\lambda$, $d_\lambda$, is given by the [hook-length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula), $d_\lambda = \frac{n!}{\prod h_\lambda (i,j)}$
>  ...where the hook length, $h_\lambda (i,j)$, is the number of cells which are either in row $i$ but not to the left of $j$ *or* in column $j$ but not above $i$.

As such

> $d_{(5,5,5,5,5)} = \frac{25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21\cdot 20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16\cdot 15\cdot 14\cdot 13\cdot 12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}$
>
>  $d_{(5,5,5,5,5)} = \frac{25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21\cdot 20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16\cdot 15\cdot 14\cdot 13\cdot 12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{(5\cdot 5)\cdot (8\cdot 6\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5)\cdot (6\cdot 3)\cdot (4\cdot 4)\cdot (5\cdot 3)\cdot (7\cdot 2)\cdot (4\cdot 3)\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot 1}$
>
>  $d_{(5,5,5,5,5)} = \frac{25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21\cdot 20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16\cdot 15\cdot 14\cdot 13\cdot 12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{25\cdot (8\cdot 6\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5)\cdot 18\cdot 16\cdot 15\cdot 14\cdot 12\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot 1}$
>
>  $d_{(5,5,5,5,5)} = \frac{24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21\cdot 20\cdot 19\cdot 17\cdot 13\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 3}{8\cdot 6\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5}$
>
>  $d_{(5,5,5,5,5)} = \frac{24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21\cdot 20\cdot 19\cdot 17\cdot 13\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 3}{(8\cdot \frac{6}{2})\cdot (7\cdot \frac{6}{2})\cdot (5\cdot 2\cdot 2)}$
>
>  $d_{(5,5,5,5,5)} = \frac{24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21\cdot 20\cdot 19\cdot 17\cdot 13\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 3}{24\cdot 21\cdot 20}$
>
>  $d_{(5,5,5,5,5)} = 23\cdot 22\cdot 19\cdot 17\cdot 13\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 3$
>
>  $d_{(5,5,5,5,5)} = 701149020$

Note that with $9$ students this would be:

> $d_{(3,3,3)} = \frac{9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}$
>
>  $d_{(3,3,3)} = \frac{9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{(3\cdot 3)\cdot (4\cdot 2)\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}$
>
>  $d_{(3,3,3)} = \frac{9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{9\cdot 8\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}$
>
>  $d_{(3,3,3)} = 7\cdot 6 = 42$

In general for squares of side $n$ these are the

> $n$<sup>th</sup> $n$-dimensional Catalan numbers
>  with an entry at [OEIS A039622](https://oeis.org/A039622)

...and for rectangles of sides $m,n$ the result has

> an entry at [OEIS A060854](https://oeis.org/A060854)

Comment: very good explanation! u even explained th general formula thanks.